# how can I get add extra get parameter to href in js?

Tags: javascript

how can I get add extra get parameter to href in js?
I want to remove refer_id=xxx in url ,then add a new refer_id=xxx get parameter to it. the url is not unique.
Is there any fast way to do it?

```
// http://www.newpm.com/
// http://www.newpm.com/?refer_id=100
// http://www.newpm.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&refer_id=100
// http://www.newpm.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&refer_id=100&from_home
// http://www.newpm.com/index.php?refer_id=100&from_home
```

for example:

```
// http://www.newpm.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&refer_id=100&from_home
```

replace refer_id=xxx get:

```
// http://www.newpm.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&&from_home
```

the replaced url has "&&",then add a new refer_id

```
// http://www.newpm.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&from_home&refer_id=200
```

Comment: Use `window.location.search = "queryString"`. Query string means the things after the `?` in the URL.

Comment: It is unclear what question you are asking.  Are you asking how to parse query parameters out of the current page's URL?  Or are you asking how to change the href on an existing link in the page using javascript.

Comment: @DJDavid98 not 100% accurate... `alert(location.search)` will return the `?`

Comment: @charlietfl I was only talking about setting it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well in general, this is how you would replace it..

```
var newVal = 'value here';
yourLink = yourLink.replace(/([&?]refer_id=)[^&#]*/,'$1'+newVal);
```

now, what you have NOT been clear on is WHAT url you are wanting to replace.  Are you wanting to replace the parameter in the actual page URL, as in, the URL in your browser bar? Or are you trying to replace a `href` attribute in an anchor tag? Or do you already have the url in some variable?   The principle of the code above is basically the same, though what `yourLink` variable you act on differs depending on *what* you want to change.